# Windows 7 Screen Margins

Tags: windows

I would like for my screen to reserve space for an application i made, So for example
70px of screen 1, should be reserved and not allow for full screen applications to expand Into this area,   is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is functionality similar to the Taskbar, and is implemented by Application Desktop ToolBars (AppBars for short). They're documented in [Using Application Desktop Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and implemented using [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [APPBARDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.